# r.html.render not rendering/waiting (when it usually does) (requests-html)

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-requests-html

Using requests-html render works fine in standalone test project, but not working when copy-pasted into actual project.

Problem inside **HD function** below: **Outputs 1**, then fails TRY statement on r.html.render and **outputs Error**

P.S. poll_interval is a few times per second

P.S.S. Python 3.9,

```
# INSERT import statements (incl. asyncio, requests-html, web3)
# INSERT a ton of redundant functions (for this question) HERE


def HD(tA, tS, numTokensBought):
    if (tA != None):
        try:
            GetRequestURL = "https://url/?address=" + tA
            from requests_html import HTMLSession
            session = HTMLSession()
            r = session.get(GetRequestURL)
            print(1) #SUCCESS
            r.html.render(timeout=0, sleep=5) #FAIL IMMEDIATELY
            print(2)
            idea = r.html.find('#fig div div', first=True)
            print(3)
        except:
            print("error")
hpTokenThread = threading.Thread(target=HD(None, None, None))
hpTokenThread.start()


def FT(event):
    try:
        HD(tA, tS, nB)
    except:
        pass

async def tLoop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        try:
            for PairC in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                FT(PairC)
            await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
        except:
            pass

def main():
    event_filter = "redundant_for_this_question_but_works_normally"
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                tLoop(event_filter, 0)))              
    finally:
        main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

input("")
```

Comment: Remove `except: print("error")` and see what the actual error is.

Comment: @MattDMo Three days of headache solved with your one 5 second comment. Thank you sir

Comment: it was "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead." for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future

Comment: You're quite welcome. Open an interactive Python console and type `import this`. It's "The Zen of Python", and while they're not hard and fast *rules*, they're very good advice for most situations. The relevant one here: *"Errors should never pass silently."*

Comment: Hint: [Guido van Rossum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum), Python's creator, is Dutch.

Comment: Solved: Using a lambda function and calling asession outside od function: